# Insert into table values from another table only if they meet certain criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, opencart

I'm trying to create the following pseudocode in MySQL. I have the following tables:

- specials
- product_filter

The `product_filter` table only has two columns, `product_id` and `filter_id`

I'd like to come up with a SQL that:

1. Reads all product_ids from the `specials` table and puts them in the `product_filter` table
2. When reading the product id from the `specials` table, it needs to look at the `price` column too
3. If the price is under $100, the filter id would be 1
4. If the price is between $100 and $500, the filter id would be 2
5. If the price is between $500 and $1000, the filter id would be 3

Here is what I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO product_filter (product_id,filter_id)
SELECT product_id, 
FROM specials;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using a `CASE` to determine what the `filter_id` is (this will set anything that doesn't have a price in those boundaries equal to 0):

```
INSERT INTO product_filter (product_id,filter_id)
SELECT product_id,
    (CASE WHEN price < 100 then 1
    WHEN price >= 100 AND price < 500 then 2
    WHEN price >= 500 AND price < 1000 then 3
    ELSE 0 END) AS filter_id
FROM specials;
```

Here's a working [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/086a7/1).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I haven't tested this yet, but what would happen if the price is exactly $100? Should I change the second WHEN to price >= instead?

Comment: @farjam Yeah, if you want the ones that are exactly 100, and exactly 500 to be 2 and 3 respectively, change that to `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

try this query (you didn't specify for values higher than 1000 so it'll make filter_id 4 if values are greater than 1000).

```
INSERT INTO product_filter (product_id,filter_id)
SELECT product_id,
       CASE WHEN price < 100 THEN 1
            WHEN price BETWEEN 100 AND 500 THEN 2
            WHEN price BETWEEN 500 AND 1000 THEN 3
            ELSE 4
       END as filter_id
FROM specials;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO product_filter (product_id,filter_id)
SELECT
  product_id, 
  (CASE
       WHEN price < 100 THEN 1 
       WHEN price BETWEEN 100 AND 500 THEN 2
       WHEN price BETWEEN 500 AND 1000 THEN 3
   END) as filter_id
 FROM specials;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You also need minor change in between clause range values as shown below:

```
INSERT INTO product_filter (product_id,filter_id)
SELECT product_id, 
       case when price < 100 then 1 -- price under $100, the filter id be 1
            -- price between $100 and $500, the filter id be 2
            when price between 101 and 500 then 2
            -- price between $500 and $1000, the filter id be 3
            when price between 501 and 1000 then 3
            -- else ? -- fill this as you need
FROM specials;
```